# Create polygons of the boundary of a Raster in R

Tags: raster, r, rgdal, terra

I want to create two polygons.

1. One is of the rectangular extents of my raster. I know I can obtain the extent of the raster using
   `r <- raster("band5.tif") 
   e <- extent(r)`
   `plot(e)` gives me this:
   [image]
2. How can I create ONE polygon of the boundary of the raster as shown below?

This is what my raster looks like:[image: raster("band5.tif")]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
library(raster)
# example data
x <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
```

To get the rectangular extent

```
e <- extent(x)
# coerce to a SpatialPolygons object
p <- as(e, 'SpatialPolygons')
```

To get a polygon that surrounds cells that are not NA

```
# make all values the same. Either do
r <- x > -Inf
# or alternatively
# r <- reclassify(x, cbind(-Inf, Inf, 1))

# convert to polygons (you need to have package 'rgeos' installed for this to work)
pp <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve=TRUE)

# look at the results
plot(x)
plot(p, lwd=5, border='red', add=TRUE)
plot(pp, lwd=3, border='blue', add=TRUE)
```

Five years later: Nowadays I would use `terra`, which does this much faster.

```
library(terra)
z <- rast(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))
pe <- as.polygons(ext(z))
pr <- as.polygons(z > -Inf)

plot(z)
plot(pe, lwd=5, border='red', add=TRUE)
plot(pr, lwd=3, border='blue', add=TRUE)
```

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on the `r <- r > -Inf` part. What is it exactly doing? And how different is it from `values(r)[!is.na(values(r))] <- 1` (which sets all locations that are not NA in r to 1).

Comment: `r > -Inf` is basic `R` . Do `c(1,NA,3,NA) > -Inf` to see how it works. I have added an alternative (`reclassify`). Your alternative works but it is not a good one for large objects.

Comment: I'm just waiting for my computer to process the `rasterToPolygons()` part, and thereupon I shall evaluate your answer. Thanks for the `-Inf` bit its going to be very useful!

Comment: For a very large raster this will take a while, or may even fail. In that case you could consider first using `aggregate` as you would not see the difference anyway.

Comment: Even with only 100 cells after running the `aggregate()` on r, it has not processed (computer equipped with 16 GB RAM). Problem is I need to keep the boundary as native as I can, since a DEM needs to be extracted from the resultant polygon. If I further down-sample my raster I will loose that boundary. Any work around?

Comment: The example has 9200 cells and runs in about a second --- which is slow, but I do not see how it would not work for 100 cells.