# Closing Gaps in QGIS contour lines

Tags: merge, contour, gap

I'm creating a contour map from a DEM, but the lines have gaps on the edge, what should I do to get rid of them? I've attached a screenshot below showing the type of area I need to fix[image: Arrows pointing at caps in contour]

Comment: A screen shot would help to explain the problem.

Comment: I don't see any contours. Your screen shot shows country outlines and there's nothing wrong. That's just the limits of the projection.

Comment: If your screen shot isn't showing contours but just the extent with the continents showing how big it is, to close up the open ends you could use the extract layer extent or create layer from extent tools with the raster as the input as suggested in Taras's answer of this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/creating-polygon-with-extents-of-raster-file-in-qgis

Comment: This is only one layer that I displayed as an example, I thought it would be too messy to display all at once